# How disable/enable an Output File Node from python?

Tags: python, rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I have the next composition that I render from Python. How can I disable/enable the rendering of a specific node?

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the [`mute`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Node.html?highlight=mute#bpy.types.Node.mute) flag of the [Node](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Node.html?highlight=mute#module-bpy.types) to `True`.

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
compositing_node_tree = scene.node_tree
compositing_node_tree.nodes['File Output'].mute = True
```

Alternatively you can just call the [`bpy.ops.node.mute_toggle()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.node.html?highlight=mute#bpy.ops.node.mute_toggle) operator within the compositor.